# Splitting a dataframe every other column to create two separate files

Tags: r, optimization

I want to (as ever) use code that performs better but functions equivalently to the following:

```
write.table(results.df[seq(1, ncol(results.df),2)],file="/path/file.txt", row.names=TRUE, sep="\t") 
write.table(results.df[seq(2, ncol(results.df),2)],file="/path/file2.txt",row.names=TRUE, sep="\t")
```

`results.df` is a dataframe that looks something thus:

```
row.names 171401    171401 111201     111201
    1      1     0.8320923  10     0.8320923
    2      2     0.8510621  11     0.8510621
    3      3     0.1009001  12     0.1009001
    4      4     0.9796110  13     0.9796110
    5      5     0.4178686  14     0.4178686
    6      6     0.6570377  15     0.6570377
    7      7     0.3689075  16     0.3689075
```

There is no consistent patterning in the column headers except that each one is repeated twice consecutively.

I want to create (1) one file with only odd-numbered columns of `results.df` and (2) another file with only even-numbered columns of `results.df`. I have one solution above, but was wondering whether there is a better-performing means of achieving the same thing.

IDEA UPDATE: I was thinking there may be some way of excising - deleting it from memory - each processed column rather than just copying it. This way the size of the dataframe progressively decreases and may result in a performance increase???

Comment: Surely the generation of those sequences is not any sort of bottleneck.

Comment: @DWin Yes: there are about 1000 columns and 2 million rows. The above data is just indicative of the pattern.

Comment: I do not think that a single call to `seq` will be any sort of bottleneck in that process.

Comment: Possibly not the `seq` itself but each statement containing `seq` certainly is. I'm not necessarily looking to eliminate `seq` (although Dason's suggestion is probably better). I thought it necessary to mention how the data from the dataframe should be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is only slightly shorter but...

```
# Instead of 
results.df[seq(1, ncol(results.df), 2]
results.df[seq(2, ncol(results.df), 2]
#you could use 
results.df[c(T,F)]
results.df[c(F,T)]
```

Comment: That works well and it does speed things up. How about `write.table` though... is there anything faster than that?

Comment: I don't think so - you want to write a table and using write.table is about the best way to do that that I know of...

Comment: @Kaleb As clearly documented in `?write.table`, if you have many columns `write.table` may be slow since it _necessarily_ has to check what type each column is. If each column is numeric, it may be faster to write a matrix than a data frame.

Comment: There's a mix of logical & numeric data that I want to include for future data sets. For this particular set of data, a numeric - hence a matrix - may be suitable. I suppose `0-1` instead of `TRUE`-`FALSE` is an option however. I was wondering though whether any package that provided an alternative to write.table.

Comment: @Kaleb Writing to disk will in general be limited more by your hard drive and OS. If you want faster write times, buy a faster HD.